# Cloud Deploy Dynamic Click Pane Plot

Tags: cloud-deploy

I was wondering if anyone has a solution as to why the following code which works in Mathematica 12.0, doesn't work when using Cloud Deploy?

```
CloudDeploy@
 DynamicModule[{pt = {\[Pi]/2, 3}}, 
  ClickPane[
   Plot[3 Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}, 
    Epilog -> {Dynamic@Arrow[{{1, 5}, pt}], Text["Extremum", {2, 5}]},
     PlotRange -> 
     6], (With[{x = (2 Round[-1/2 + #[[1]]/\[Pi]] + 1) \[Pi]/2}, 
      pt = {x, 3 Sin[x]}]) &]]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Quick check with examples from documentation shows that ClickPane does not seem fully supported on WPC yet. I guess it boils down to not supporting `MousePosition["Graphics"]` which means that it will be tough to get a workaround.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll check if there is a way to replicate what I want with LocatorPane, since that has worked without any issues.